# Check for non integer value in a List

Tags: java

I am trying to iterate through a List of Strings checking if one of them can not be resolved to an integer. If one of them cannot be resolved to in integer it throws an FormatException(). But it seems the check I do does not work. There is an error and I am not sure why or how to resolve it.

```
        String s = strLine;
    List myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")));
    List<Integer> intList;
        for (int i=0;i<myList.size();i++) {
            //Check if all the values are integers
            try {

               /*Problem area----->*/ intList[i] = Integer.parseInt( (String) myList.get(i) );

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new FormatException();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren' passing in an entirely valid list?

Comment: If I am not mistaking the list at the point should be something like---> ['15','16',...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few errors in your code. I have fixed them, try the below code:

```
    String s = strLine;
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<myList.size();i++) {
            //Check if all the values are integers
            try {

               /*Problem area----->*/ intList.add(Integer.parseInt( (String) myList.get(i)));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new FormatException();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = strLine;
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")));
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String stringPart : myList) {
        //Check if all the values are integers
        try {
           int parsedString =  new Integer(stringPart);
           intList.add(parsedString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1)You have not created an arraylist myList, so create it first

2)you are using a list like an array using index but it has add method so use it

3)no exception named as formatException available in Java, in your case use NumberFormatException

below is the correct program with all above modification

```
String s = "12 23 34";
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")));
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i=0;i<myList.size();i++) {
                //Check if all the values are integers
                try {

                   /*Problem area----->*/ 
                    intList.add( Integer.parseInt( (String) myList.get(i) ));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new NumberFormatException ();
                }
            }
```

Comment: The FormatException is a custom made exception. But thank you for the rest :) was helpfull

Comment: Actually I got another question, Does the Try function actually add it or should I retype it outside the try function

Comment: can you explain it, i didnt understand what actually try adds and what you want to retype outside try

Comment: Well the main reason for "try/catch" is pick up if there is a non integer value in the list example: ['15', '16', ERROR, '25', '35']. So if I use try and it is successful will it edit new list or should I do that outside to make it edit the list?

Comment: it works in this way...if try gets no exception means all your values are integers inside list then it keeps adding new list with the parsed int values, so no need to do anything outside..if try gets exception while adding because of non integer then it wont add that element inside the new list,it directly jumps to catch and that is what we wanted, and it repeats the same for each iteration as we have a cathc block to handle the exception. so no need to edit anything outside..any other question ?

Comment: Not thank you that was all I needed to know. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

intList is and ArrayList and you cant access it via []. That is an array operator. Instead to set to an index try

```
intList.add(i, Integer.parseInt( (String) myList.get(i) ));
```

Comment: first of all there is no intList created using new , thats the first problem. then only your answer can be considered

Comment: That was just a code snippet. I may not be complete. The type of intList is given as List<Integer> intList; so anyway it should be a List. So accessing that via [] wont work.

Comment: agreed with your statement accessing that via [] wont work. but put as comment if your answer is incomplete...